# Centreon not graphing Windows Disk Check

Tags: nagios, performance-monitoring, disk-space-utilization, graph, centreon

I'm trying to figure out how to get Centreon to graph a Windows Diskspace check. The service comes back fine:

```
OK: C:\: 14.9G|'C:\ %'=63%;20;10 'C:\'=14.94GB;4;4;0;39.99
```

However, when I try to add a curve to graph this data, I get nowhere. When I look under **Administration**->**Options**->**Centstorage**->**Manage** the service(s) show metrics spelled `C-\\-%` and `C-\` but using those for Data Source names (using `C-\\\\-%` to get the `\\` to show up) under **Views**->**Graphs**->**Curves** does nothing. I've also tried defining Data Sources as `C:\ %` and `C:\` as well as `'C:\ %'` and `'C:\'` to no avail.

Finally, I've tried deleting service data and rebuilding the RRD database as well as restarting the centstorage daemon, `/etc/init.d/centstorage restart`, which *did* solve a similar problem... but not this one.

Thanks very much for your time and help.

EDIT: Noticed `C-\\-%` looked like it had no `\`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and it's a [known issue](http://forge.centreon.com/issues/2110) which is supposed to be fixed but doesn't seem to be.

I took a different approach. I read the Windows Perf counters via NRPE like this to get my free disk space in MB:

```
$USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -p 5666 -c CheckCounter -a "Counter:DiskC-FreeMB=\LogicalDisk(C:)\Free Megabytes" ShowAll MinWarn=0 MinCrit=0
```

I also have a separate check to monitor my free space as a percentage by doing:

```
$USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -p 5666 -c CheckCounter -a "Counter:DiskC-PctFree=\\LogicalDisk(C:)\\% Free Space" ShowAll MinWarn=20 MinCrit=15
```

It's not ideal but at least I have some metrics that can be graphed.